# How to write a service which updates the table every second in android

Tags: android

I am getting the value from webservice. The webservice value will change frequently. If the user uses the application offline I have to show the value to the user so from the webservice I am updating the value to db. Can anybody tell me how to write a service to update the sqlite  table every second in android? Can anybody give sample code?

Thanks

Comment: I totally DON'T!! get what your question is. seriously, is someone else asked it like this would you be able to understand it?

Comment: @DArkO he wants: A Service that updates(tells the user (i guess)) if there is something new every `x` seconds. Have a look at [THIS LINK](https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/132273/background-service-android)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Android NDK to be able to use sqlite natively in C